# `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, String>>` with sub objects(Array,Ienumeralbe)

Tags: c#

How should I adjust this example, if one of that (sub)member is again some kind of list or array ?

```
/// <summary>
///     Gets all public properties of an object and and puts them into dictionary.
/// </summary>
public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object instance)
{
    if (instance == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    // if an object is dynamic it will convert to IDictionary<string, object>
    var result = instance as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (result != null)
        return result;

    return instance.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(instance));
}
```

Comment: Would be easier if you could state the purpose...